# ArrayList vs HashMap time complexity

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, time-complexity

The scenario is the following:

You have 2 strings (s1, s2) and want to check whether one is a permutation of the other so you generate all permutations of lets say s1 and store them and then iterate over and compare against s2 until either it's found or not.

Now, in this scenario, i am deliberating whether an `ArrayList` is better to use or a `HashMap` when considering strictly time complexity as i believe both have `O(N)` space complexity.

According to the javadocs, `ArrayList` has a search complexity of `O(N)` whereas `HashMap` is `O(1)`. If this is the case, is there any reason to favor using `ArrayList` over `HashMap` here since `HashMap` would be faster?

The only potential downside i could think of is that your `(k,v)` pairs might be a bit weird if you did something like where the `key = value`, i.e. `{k = "ABCD", v = "ABCD"}`, etc..

Comment: Why do you want to implement the check this way?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Because it's the algorithm i came up with.

Comment: Generating the permutations is _extremely_ expensive, not to mention the time and space complexity to do so. There is another way to perform the check that is much cheaper. It does involve reordering the strings.

Comment: Generating all permutations is O(n!), which is really bad. It's even worse than exponential. To get an idea of how bad O(n!) is, imagine you tried to sort a deck of cards by shuffling it over and over until all the cards randomly ended up in order. That algorithm would also be [O(n!)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort).

Comment: You need to come up with a better algorithm.  Think about it.

Comment: @StephenC Yea, i've come up with a better algorithm at this point. I actually had 2 variations, one where i store the characters of both strings into a hashmap and then check the number of occurrences of each letter. The other was to simply sort each string and do an equals check. The sorting would be O(n log n) i think where n would be the longer of the 2 strings and I think this is a better run time than the hashmap version since i'd be doing essentially 3 iterations, albeit not nested. If anything, it might be cleaner code. That being said, the general question is still of interest.

Comment: Well, if you ignore the *underlying* problem that you are trying to solve, the best answer to your question is a simple No.  There are no advantages for using `ArrayList` here, apart from the memory utilization issue that you have already identified.  Hence, I would claim that the question is not of general interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-two-strings-are-permutation-of-each-other/):

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*; 
  
class GFG{ 
      
    static int NO_OF_CHARS = 256; 
      
    /* function to check whether two strings 
    are Permutation of each other */
    static boolean arePermutation(char str1[], char str2[]) 
    { 
        // Create 2 count arrays and initialize 
        // all values as 0 
        int count1[] = new int [NO_OF_CHARS]; 
        Arrays.fill(count1, 0); 
        int count2[] = new int [NO_OF_CHARS]; 
        Arrays.fill(count2, 0); 
        int i; 
   
        // For each character in input strings, 
        // increment count in the corresponding 
        // count array 
        for (i = 0; i <str1.length && i < str2.length ; 
                                                 i++) 
        { 
            count1[str1[i]]++; 
            count2[str2[i]]++; 
        } 
   
        // If both strings are of different length. 
        // Removing this condition will make the program  
        // fail for strings like "aaca" and "aca" 
        if (str1.length != str2.length) 
            return false; 
   
        // Compare count arrays 
        for (i = 0; i < NO_OF_CHARS; i++) 
            if (count1[i] != count2[i]) 
                return false; 
   
        return true; 
    } 
   
    /* Driver program to test to print printDups*/
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        char str1[] = ("geeksforgeeks").toCharArray(); 
        char str2[] = ("forgeeksgeeks").toCharArray(); 
          
        if ( arePermutation(str1, str2) ) 
            System.out.println("Yes"); 
        else
            System.out.println("No"); 
    } 
} 
  
// This code is contributed by Nikita Tiwari.
```

If you're glued to your implementation, use a HashSet, it still has O(1) lookup time, just without keys

Answer (score 0):

You can use HashSet as you need only one parameter.